# How to create a transparent image with GraphicsMagick CLI?

Tags: image-editing, graphicsmagick

I'm coming up empty handed while trying to find out how to modify the opacity of an image using the GraphicsMagick CLI. I'm simply trying to input a standard image and convert it to the corresponding image with a reduced opacity. I'm running GraphicsMagick 1.3.14. Using ImageMagick, I can issue the command:

```
convert input.png -alpha set -channel a -evaluate set 50% +channel output.png
```

However, the `-alpha` option (among others) is unrecognized as a valid GM convert option ([convert option reference here](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/convert.html#conv-opti)). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Note**: This question is a [cross post of a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11304124/301302) on StackOverflow. After posting on SO, I thought SuperUser might be a little more appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent in GraphicsMagick is

```
gm convert input.png -operator Opacity Multiply 0.5 output.png
```

or

```
gm convert input.png -operator Opacity Assign 50% output.png
```

depending on what you really want to do (modulate or assign).

You should add `-matte` prior to `-operator` if you don't know if the image already has an active opacity channel.

Bob

Comment: Thank you Bob; the addition of the `-matte` operation got me what I wanted. Appreciate the help.

Comment: This thread might be of help to some: https://sourceforge.net/p/graphicsmagick/discussion/250738/thread/4ebaf0ed/